# Spray-json Deserializing nested list of objects

Tags: json, scala, spray

I have a class that is nested in a list in another class. it looks like this

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class Person(
                     firstName: String,
                     lastName: String
                    )

object Person {
 ...
}

object PersonJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val personFormat = jsonFormat2(Person.apply)
}
```

the toJson method here works perfectly, however, this class is embedded as a list in another class like this.

```
import Person._
import PersonJsonProtocol._
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class Course(
                     courseName: String,
                     students: List[Person]
                    )

object CourseJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val courseFormat = jsonFormat2(Course)
}
```

In another class

```
import Person._
import Course._
import PersonJsonProtocol._
import CourseJsonProtocol._

new Course("English", List(persons)).toJson
// this is failing
```

However when I import this protocol and try to use the toJson method, I get " Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for Course"

I am not sure how to achieve deserializing nested list of objects, I can't find it anywhere in the docs. Did someone manage to do this before?

Best.

Comment: Can you please add the code snippet how are you converting it to json? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: It seems that you must import your personJsonProtocol to the compiler to resolve the Person protocol via implicit resolution

Comment: implicit val personFormat = jsonFormat2(Person.apply) why you are using person.apply? just use jsonFormat2(Person)

Comment: @MaheshChandKandpal added

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 It is imported correctly

Comment: @RamanMishra I have factory methods defined in the companion object. If you want the protocol defined on the companion object you need to call the apply method

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get it done by implicitly overriding the write function.

```
object CourseJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit object CourseFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Course] {
    def write(course: Course) = {
      JsObject(
              "course_name" -> JsString(course.courseName),
              "students" -> JsArray(for(student <- course.students) yield student.toJson)
              )
    }
    def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```